# Multiple file upload using XMLHttpRequest() and Aws S3

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, form-data

In the code sample below, I am trying to upload multiple files using FormData and XMLHttpRequest to a Aws S3 bucket. I intend is to send large files to the bucket using Aws Multipart Upload. It works when only one file is selected. My issue comes in during the onreadystatechange is called. Instead of sending multiple files to the uploadPart section, it will only send the most recent file. I was hoping to run the upload asynchronously.

```
function uploadFile(){
    files = _("file").files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        file = files[i];
        ownerName = _("name").value;

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("command", 'CreateMultipartUpload');
        formdata.append("filename", file.name);
        formdata.append("fileindex", i);
        formdata.append("name", ownerName);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", "FileUploader.php", true);
        ajax.send(formdata);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
                var sendBackData = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                uploadPart(sendBackData, 1);
            }
        };
        console.log("Superman!");
    }
}
```

If you have any suggestions on how I can fix my problem, feel free to reply.

Comment: I've done this a few times, and just iterated over the files, sending one at a time. It's still going to be async, and take about the same time, the multiple requests is really a small overhead.

Comment: And it looks like you're sending the files to `FileUploader.php`, not to AWS, which actually supports CORS ?